# LEFT() is not working in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I have a date in the format of 2012-08-10. I want the first four digits of the date. 
Using `extract(year from date)` works, but it will make a problem in CakePHP.

So i try to use `LEFT()` or `RIGHT()`:

```
select LEFT(date,4) from table
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why does it cause a problem for PHP? Why not do *all* of the formatting on a more suitable platform (e.g. PHP) rather than trying to do it in SQL?

Comment: In php,  $this->set('srchDate', $this->Holiday->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Holiday.id','extract(year from "Holiday"."date")')))); it is not working.

Comment: Just for the future, it's generally a good idea to (a) mention your PostgreSQL version, and (b) show exact error messages, not just "it is not working".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use substring if you dont want to use extract like

```
select substring('2012-4-03',1,4);
```

or use `select to_char(some_date, 'YYYY') from table;`

you can also write a function calling left for the same.but there is no inbuilt function in postgresql.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the four digit year from a `date` as a string then [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) is what you want:

```
select to_char(some_date, 'YYYY') from table;
```

Actually, pretty much any date or time formatting inside the database should be done with `to_char` so you might want to read [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).

[LEFT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) won't work because LEFT wants a string argument but you're giving it a `date`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [EXTRACT()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) if you want to extract the year from a DATE:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fieldname) FROM tablename;
```

Or TO_CHAR(), as mentioned by others.